# Update an average-computing cell by pushing new data to it

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell that contains the following formula: `=AVERAGE(41.79, 36.76)` (which results in `39.275`).

I want a way, using VBA, to "append" data to this average, so that my cell becomes `=AVERAGE(41.79, 36.76, 50.00)` for example.

Ideally I'd want a stateless way of doing this, i.e. not using an array to store the average's content somewhere other than the cell... Unless it's the only to do it.

For the context, I'm writing a sheet that aggregates data in days. I have a widget that allows me to push new input data, if today's date's row doesn't exist in my table, it's created (populated with the input data), else the row's averages are updated with the input data.

Here is a screenshot of the sheet, in which the yellow cells are examples of such "average-computing" cells:

[image: The yellow cells are "aggregates"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barusseau, where is the cell containing the average formula please? Also, is the data above already in a table? If it is then you can always set the average to calculate based on the [Accuracy] column and this should auto-update when new data is added. If not, then you can do it via VBA presumably whenever you click the "Add results to sheet" button with the following:

```
Cells(?, ?).Formula = Replace(Cells(?, ?).Formula, ")", "") & "," & newNumber & ")"
```

Note I've put question marks as I don't know where the cell that contains the average formula is located. Also [newNumber] would just be whatever new number you want added to the average i.e. 50.00 from your example above.

Comment: I see! That looks good. I'll try to do that on my cells, thanks.